# Memory leak warnings while shutting down tomcat server running a camel application

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am running a spring based camel application in tomcat server. When I shutdown the tomcat server i see below in the logs which suggests I may have an memory leak:

## Logs

SEVERE: The web application [/xxx-v001] appears to have started a thread named [CamelJettyServer(0x62e871db)-1036] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 16, 2015 7:08:34 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads

I am using Jetty Http component in my route:

```
<bean id="jettyOutbound" class="org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent" destroy-method="shutdown">     
           <property name="minThreads" value="1024"/>
           <property name="maxThreads" value="1024"/>
           <property name="httpClientMinThreads" value="64"/>
           <property name="httpClientMaxThreads" value="64"/>
    </bean>
```

The problem is after i completely shutdown tomcat i still see few threads hanging out. I need to manually kill them by using "kill -9 pid" after getting the list of threads (ps -aef | grep tomcat). I tried putting the shutdown method but it still doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a shutdown hook for the component as documented in the [javadoc](http://org.apache.camel.ShutdownableService). It looks to be doStop() in this case.

Generally, you should put this in a lifecycle listener, such as a  `ServletContextListener.contextDestoyed()`